# print everything before/after the nth matching line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I'd like to print both everything before the 2nd line that **begins** with `* i` (asterisk, space, lowercase letter I) excluding the line and everything after that line including the line separately.

For example, if I had a text file like this:

```
* misc: go to the park
with your dog 
* important: sell badges
the bigger the pricier
24 left right now
* important: go to the mall
get clothes
* important: finish homework
```

I'd like to print this first:

```
* misc: go to the park
with your dog
* important: sell badges
the bigger the pricier
24 left right now
```

and then this:

```
* important: go to the mall
get clothes
* important: finish homework
```

How can I do this using sed?

I tried

```
sed  '/\* [^i]/,$   { /\* [^i]/,$ d}' /path/to/txt/
```

but it just prints everything before the **1st** matching line.

**I'd like to have two separate scripts for extracting each part.**

Comment: you want those two outputs in separate files? also, please add what efforts you've made to solve this.. and, does it have to be with sed only?

Comment: thanks for adding your efforts :) am still not clear what you mean by print first portion and then next portion...

Comment: Yes. Outputting to stdout is also okay. Sed is preferred but if it's not possible, I can use other commands too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest **`awk`** processing (which, I believe, will be more flexible and robust):

```
awk '/^\* i/ && ++c == 2{ print r ORS; r=""; c=0 }
     { r=(r? r ORS:"")$0 }
     END{ print r }' file
```

The output:

```
* misc: go to the park
with your dog 
* important: sell badges
the bigger the pricier
24 left right now

* important: go to the mall
get clothes
* important: finish homework
```

---

For your current simple case (without additional logic) - it may be shortened to the following:

```
awk '/^\* i/ && ++c == 2{ print "" }1' file
```

---

To extract the needed part separately - still with a single `awk` command but using dynamic argument `part` which accepts conditional value either `1` (1st section, preceding section) or `2` (2nd section, following section).

Scheme:

**`awk -v part=[12] '/^\* i/ && ++c == 2{ if (part == 1) exit; else f=1 }
        part == 1 || (part == 2 && f)' FILE`**

Usage:

-- print *"before"* section:

```
$ awk -v part=1 '/^\* i/ && ++c==2{ if (part==1) exit; else f=1 }
>         part==1 || (part==2 && f)' file
* misc: go to the park
with your dog 
* important: sell badges
the bigger the pricier
24 left right now
```

---

-- print *"after"* section:

```
$ awk -v part=2 '/^\* i/ && ++c==2{ if (part==1) exit; else f=1 }
>         part==1 || (part==2 && f)' file
* important: go to the mall
get clothes
* important: finish homework
```

Comment: if that's the output OP needs, why not a simple `awk '/^\* i/ && ++c==2{print ""} 1'`? ;)

Comment: @Sundeep, you have my edit. The former approach will allow adding additional logic to the captured lines (or while capturing each section)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Oh, that's a bit different than what I wanted. I want to run one program to show everything before the matching line and the other for everything after that, but how can I delete unnecessary part instead of inserting an empty line after that?

Comment: @stacko, if there would be 2 different scripts each outputting a separate section - why caring of "delete unnecessary part"?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have various text to insert between those parts. I'm on OSX and will run those kinds of bash scripts from Applescript and that often causes weird errors that probably won't happen in Linux so I want to keep things separate first and append stuff in a dummy file to achieve this kind of task.

Comment: @stacko, here you are, see my update

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Wow they work like a charm, thanks! I really should learn awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed too, It's more complicated than awk

```
cat sedscript.sh

deb=$1
sed 's/.*/'"$deb"'\n&/
:A
/^1/{
N
/\n\* i/!bA
:B
N
/\n\* i[^\n]*$/!bB
s/\n[^\n]*$//
s/[^\n]*\n//
q
}
:C
/^2/{
N
/\n\* i/!bC
:D
N
/\n\* i[^\n]*$/!bD
s/.*\n//
:E
N
bE
q
}
d
' $2
```

Call it like that :

for the first part

./sedscript.sh 1 infile

for the second part

./sedscript.sh 2 infile